# How to implement bounce off collision between two nodes in ARKIT-Scenekit of iOS 11?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, arkit, xcode9beta6

I am trying to implement collision bounce off between two nodes. From what i learnt, collision property will be set by default and if there is any contact between two nodes, it will bounce back. I have multiple virtual 3D objects that i add into scene. There is a provision for user to move the object anywhere. For example, let us say i have two objects table and chair, if i move chair towards the table, the chair overlaps with the table. But what i need is chair should bounce back since we already have table in that position.

I have multiple objects placed liked this. And user can move any object anywhere. But no two objects should overlap with each other.

I tried setting contactbitmask  and collisionbitmask but no luck(I have 6 scenefiles and i have given values from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 as category masks and 62, 61, 59, 55, 47, 31 as collision and contact masks respectively for nodes of each scenefile).

I even tried using contactTestBetween but no idea what it returns and how to find out if there is contact between two bodies using this method. I understand it returns point of contact, impulse, penetration distance etc. but with these how to find out if there is contact between 2 nodes?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @mike_t No luck :(

Comment: You Have to apply physics body to it `SCNPhysicsBody`.  `kinematic`  is good choice for your requirement